# Function firing twice when bound to before callback using jQuery cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm using the [jQuery Background Position](http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPosRef.html) plugin and the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin to try to make a slider and a background image animate at the same time the slides are scrolling. Here's a sample of what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="pane">
            Text asd dddsa sadsad
        </div>
        <div class="pane">
            Text asd dddsa sadsad
        </div> 
        <div class="pane">
            Text asd dddsa sadsad
        </div>        
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="prev-slide">&lt; Prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next-slide">Next &gt;</a>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    // Animate background when clicking slider arrows
    $('#prev-slide').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        slideBgForward();
    });

    $('#next-slide').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        slideBgBackward();
    });

    $('.slider').cycle({
        fx   : 'scrollHorz',
        next : '#next-slide',
        prev : '#prev-slide',
        before : function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
            if (forwardFlag) {
                slideBgBackward();
            } else {
                slideBgForward();
            }                
        }            
    });

    // Slide background forwards
    function slideBgForward() {
        $('.container').animate({
            backgroundPosition: '-=20% 0'
        }, 1500);
    }

    // Slide background backwards
    function slideBgBackward() {
        $('.container').animate({
            backgroundPosition: '-=20% 0'
        }, 1500);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/gshtZ/

If I leave the slider scroll by itself it works as intended, however if I click the next/prev links to move trough the slides the background animates twice, I believe it's because the slide functions are being called when the links is clicked AND before the slide starts scrolling. Is there a way to make it just scroll once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have asked `('.slider').cycle()` to handle your `next` and `prev`, **AND** you are also asking jQuery to handle them too - and each is doing what you ask, and as such, your background is animating twice.

I would be tempted to try removing / disabling `$('#next-slide').on('click')` and `$('#prev-slide').on('click')` and see what happens.

Comment: Also note that `slideBgForward()` should set the background position to `'+=20% 0'`, not `'-=20% 0'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I forgot that the `before` callback fired after clicking the links as well so there was no need for the "on click" functions. About the `+=20% 0` that was a copy/paste mistake sorry.